# Need help optimizing some Rails 2.3 ActiveRecord code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, activerecord

(Hi Dr. Nick!)

I'm trying to tighten things up for our app admin, and in a few places we have some pretty skeezy code.

For example, we have Markets, which contain Deals.  In several places, we do something like this:

```
@markets = Market.find(:all, :select => ['name, id'])
@deals = Deal.find(:all, :select => ['subject, discount_price, start_time, end_time'], :conditions => ['start_time >= ? AND end_time <= ?', date1 date2])
```

Then in the corresponding view, we do something like this:

```
@markets.each do |m|
  =m.name
end

@deals.sort!{ |a,b| a.market.name <=> b.market.name }
@deals.each do |d|
  =d.subject
  =d.market.name
end
```

This runs a stupid amount of queries: one to get the market names and ids, then another to get all the deal info, and then for each deal (of which there are thousands), we run **yet another** query to retrieve the market name, which we already have!

Tell me there is a way to get everything I need with just one query, since it's all related anyway, or at least to clean this up so it's not such a nightmare.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write like this way ..

```
@deals_with_market_name = Deal.find(:all, :include => :market, 
:select => ['subject, discount_price, start_time, end_time,market.name as market_name'], 
:conditions => ['start_time >= ? AND end_time <= ?', date1 date2], 
:order => "market.name")
```

And in view ...

```
@deals.each do |a|
  =a.subject
  =a.market_name
end
```

Try it...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `:include => :market` when searching the `deals` you won't run a query to retrieve the `market` name for each `deal`. It'll be eager loaded.

```
@deals = Deal.find(:all, :include => :market)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had thought of that, but then I'm still needing something for the @markets.each do { |m| = m.name } block

Comment: The way I told you, you'll solve your problem with 3 queries. I can't think any other way to do this using less queries. If you change your view to one loop only, you can reduce to 2 queries.